# How do I click a button to play different sounds in relation to text input in entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm still working on the translation app, translating English words to my native language, Meta', using a Python dictionary.

I've created a play button that can only play single audio. I want to be able to play various sounds in my native language from a folder on my PC depending on what key I input in the entry widget. In other words, the keys define the condition for what sound is played when I click the play button (I don't yet know how to go about if-else statements). For example, if "ear" is input and I click the play button, the word should be read out in my native language (I have the audio recordings in a subfolder on my pc). Unfortunately, my native language is not yet on Google Translate.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter. messagebox
root=Tk()
root.geometry('250x250')
root.title("Meta' Translator")
root.configure(background="#35424a")
from playsound import playsound

#Entry widget object
textin = StringVar()

#press ENTER key to activate translate button
def returnPressed(event):
    clk()

def clk():
    entered = ent.get().lower() #get user input and convert to lowercase
    output.delete(0.0,END)
    if len(entered) > 0:
        try:
            textin = exlist[entered]
        except:
            textin = 'Word not found'
        output.insert(0.0,textin)

def play():
    playsound('wan.mp3')

#heading
lab0=Label(root,text='Translate English Words to Meta\'',bg="#35424a",fg="silver",font= 
('none 11 bold'))
lab0.place(x=0,y=2)

#Entry field
ent=Entry(root,width=15,font=('Times 18'),textvar=textin,bg='white')
ent.place(x=30,y=30)

#focus on entry widget
ent.focus()

#Search button
but=Button(root,padx=1,pady=1,text='Translate',command=clk,bg='powder blue',font=('none 18 bold'))
but.place(x=60,y=90)

#press ENTER key to activate Translate button
root.bind('<Return>', returnPressed)

#output field
output=Text(root,width=15,height=1,font=('Times 18'),fg="black")
output.place(x=30,y=170)

#play button
play_button=Button(root,padx=1,pady=1,text='Play',command=play,bg='powder blue',font=('none 10 bold'))
play_button.place(x=100,y=210)

#prevent sizing of window
root.resizable(False,False) 

#Dictionary
exlist={
    "hat":"ɨ̀də̀m", 
    "hoe":"əsɔ́",
    "honey":"jú",
    "chest":"ɨgɔ̂",
    "eye":"ɨghə́",
    "ear":"ǝ̀tǒŋ",
    }

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why not add a list as values for the `exlist` with the first value of each being the translation and the second being the path to the files and when play is pressed just use the second value from the list to play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
def play():
    text = output.get("0.0", "end").strip("\n") # Also I have to remove the annoying new line at the end
    if text == "test1":
        playsound("test1.mp3")
    elif text == "test2":
        playsound("test2.mp3")
    elif text == "test3":
        playsound("test3.mp3")
    else:
        # If there is no sound file for the translation:
        playsound("unknown.mp3")
```

Basically if the translation is `"test1"` then it will play the "test1.mp3". If the translation is `"test2"` then it will play the "test2.mp3" ...

Comment: I have followed your procedure, but irrespective of what word is in the output widget, only the "unknown.mp3" plays; ie. only the audio file after the else condition is played. The machine doesn't seem to recognize the "if" or "elif" conditions. What could be the problem?

Comment: @DieudonneTambah Does it work now? I fixed my mistake

Comment: Thanks a lot. The update worked. I appreciate your effort. But now, instead of using words in the output widget as the condition for playing sound, how do we do it from the entry widget? ie. is so and so word is typed in the entry widget, and the play button is clicked, let this and that sound be played. Thanks.

Comment: @DieudonneTambah If I understand what you mean correctly you can just change the `output.get("0.0", "end")` to `ent.get()`. It will play the sound of the input instead of the output.

Comment: I got it! Thanks.